# T-SQL Cursor never ends

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I already searched with Google but I didn't find answer to my question. In the internet everything says that I do it correct. 
My problem is - I am trying for now write values what I saved to cursor (yes, only that). However loop which I use for it is infinity and it writes all values from cursor from start to end, after again and again and again ...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CreateOrEditClient(...Parameters...) AS
DECLARE c CURSOR FOR SELECT column FROM table;
DECLARE @wrt VARCHAR(20);
DECLARE @tmp INT = 0;
 BEGIN
  OPEN c;
   FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @wrt;
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
     BEGIN
      print CAST(@tmp AS VARCHAR(10)) + '  ' + @wrt;
      SET @tmp = @tmp +1;
      FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @wrt;
     END;
  CLOSE c;
  DEALLOCATE c;
END;

EXEC CreateOrEditClient ...;
```

In my opinion cursor is written correct but output is:

```
0  790710/1112
1  900519/5555
2  790716/7877
....
19 111111/1111
0  790710/1112
1  900519/5555
....
```

and in the end it writes error message "Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32)."

If I use only

```
SELECT column FROM table;
```

It writes only 20 records.

I know there is better solution for this example but I need to know why the Cursor doesn't work. It may be useful in future. Thanks for every asnwer.

Comment: from where you calling the procedure

Comment: You've "select column from table" in the cursor posted, what is your original cursor query.

Comment: Are you sure, in removing things for this post, you haven't removed something important? You'd see something like this if that outer `BEGIN`/`END` block was also preceded by a `WHILE`.

Comment: Perhaps the stored procedure calls itself recursively - you might have included `EXEC CreateOrEditClient` in stored procedure by mistake.

Comment: EXEC CreateOrEditClient ...; is this line is in your store procedure

Comment: Something is wrong with your output. The `@tmp` variable is not reset to 0 inside your loop, but the output shows that at some point `@tmp` is set back to 0. Looks like it's not the cursor - it's the whole procedure that is called several times.

Comment: Would be better to explain what do you want at the end of the day. Using cursors is never the solution.

Comment: -> AmitSingh, Only marked it and run. (in new tab it works at the same way). 
Yes you have right, I complited the procedure but the calling of procedure was under that. I thought it will be ignored (I think in PL/SQL it does) 
 
-> Sunny, same as I wrote here.
 
-> Damien_The_Unbeliever, Yea pretty sure.
 
-> NikolaMarkovinović, Hmm, you have right, I thought it will save only procedure and all after last 'END;' will be ignored, I tried gave it away and it started work correct. 
 
In total, thank you for your answers, problem is solved.

Comment: Add your answer as an answer to be able to close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, in comments under question is solution.

"EXEC ProcedureName ...;" can't be in the same file like procedure's body when you compile.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CreateOrEditClient(...Parameters...) AS
DECLARE c CURSOR FOR SELECT column FROM table;
DECLARE @wrt VARCHAR(20);
DECLARE @tmp INT = 0;
 BEGIN
  OPEN c;
   FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @wrt;
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
 BEGIN
  print CAST(@tmp AS VARCHAR(10)) + '  ' + @wrt;
    SET @tmp = @tmp +1;
    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @wrt;
 END;
  CLOSE c;
  DEALLOCATE c;
END;
```

The example in question will call procedure recursively.
Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably notice if you would keep your code indented correctly. You have:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CreateOrEditClient(...Parameters...) AS
DECLARE c CURSOR FOR SELECT column FROM table;
DECLARE @wrt VARCHAR(20);
DECLARE @tmp INT = 0;
BEGIN
    OPEN c;
        FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @wrt;
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            print CAST(@tmp AS VARCHAR(10)) + '  ' + @wrt;
            SET @tmp = @tmp +1;
            FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @wrt;
        END;
    CLOSE c;
    DEALLOCATE c;
END;
```

You should have:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CreateOrEditClient(...Parameters...) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @wrt VARCHAR(20);
    DECLARE @tmp INT = 0;
    DECLARE c CURSOR FOR SELECT column FROM table;
    OPEN c;
        FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @wrt;
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            print CAST(@tmp AS VARCHAR(10)) + '  ' + @wrt;
            SET @tmp = @tmp +1;
            FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @wrt;
        END;
    CLOSE c;
    DEALLOCATE c;
END;

EXEC CreateOrEditClient ...;
```

BTW. Did your code even run? Seems like a syntax error to me.

EDIT: Oh, and parameters are not declared in brackets AFAIK. For example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE tmp_mol_cleanup_db
    @param1 type,
    @param2 type
AS
BEGIN
    -- procedure body
END;
```

Comment: What do you think is a syntax error? a `BEGIN`/`END` block is *not* required for a stored procedure definition, and, vice versa, you're allowed to introduce one wherever a statement is expected.

Comment: OK maybe not a syntax error, but if `DECLARE c ...` is the only line inside the procedure (and that's what probably happens), then `c` should be undeclared when you try to do `OPEN c;`.

Comment: incorrect. The body of a stored procedure (in SQL Server) is defined from the `AS` until the end of the batch; typically, a `GO` if this is part of a larger script, or the end of the script.

Comment: Hm... That's kind of crazy and very error prone. Very bad syntax decision on Microsoft side. Non the less my suggestion should work and you explained why it looped and haven't shown an error.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this ...

```
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON ;
    DECLARE @wrt VARCHAR(20)
    DECLARE @tmp INT = 0

    DECLARE Cur_Common CURSOR  FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY FOR   
    SELECT iID FROM 'YourTable'
    OPEN Cur_Common
    FETCH NEXT FROM Cur_Common INTO @wrt

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
        BEGIN
            print CAST(@tmp AS VARCHAR(10)) + '  ' + @wrt;
SET @tmp = @tmp +1;

       FETCH NEXT FROM Cur_Common INTO @wrt
        END
        CLOSE Cur_Common
    DEALLOCATE Cur_Common
END
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 DECLARE @tmp INT
 SET @tmp=0
```

instad of 
`DECLARE @tmp INT = 0`

Comment: That part is fine, you can do that in SQL.